# Predicting future values with sklearn.preprocessing 's PolynomialRegression feature

Tags: python

I am working on a very basic stock analyzer that gets its stock info from yfinance and uses Polynomial Regression to get a prediction for all of the present/past data that I put into it. How would I get information from the line (e.g. `print(f"tomorrow's prediction is: {model.predict(future_point_in_time)}")` and get it to output it's predicted output for said future point? Or, if that is not possible, is there a way for me to get the equation of the line so I can use that to predict my line?

Here's my full code, sorry it's messy

```
import yfinance as yf
import sys
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
att = yf.Ticker("T")
# get all stock info
att_info = att.info
historical_market_data = []
# get historical market data
hist = att.history(period="1mo")
days = 0
for i in range(len(hist)):
  days += 1
  historical_market_data.append([hist.High.iloc[i], hist.Low.iloc[i], hist.Open.iloc[i], hist.Close.iloc[i], hist.Volume.iloc[i], hist.Dividends.iloc[i], days])
'''
Item 0: High of the day
Item 1: Low of the day
Item 2: Price at opening
Item 3: Price at closing
Item 4: Volume
Item 5: Dividends
Item 6: Day
'''
line1 = []
line2 = []
line3 = []
line4 = []
line5 = []
line6 = []
days = []
avgs = []
for i in historical_market_data:
  line1.append(i[0])
  line2.append(i[1])
  avgs.append((i[0] + i[1]) / 2)
  line3.append(i[2])
  line4.append(i[3])
  line5.append(i[4])
  line6.append(i[5])
  days.append(i[6])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#the data at the end of the lists is sketchy, so it needs removal
del line1[-1]
del line2[-1]
del line3[-1]
del line4[-1]
del line5[-1]
del line6[-1]
del days[-1]
plt.plot(days, line1)
plt.plot(days, line2)
plt.plot(days, line3)
plt.plot(days, line4)


plt.legend(labels=['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Predicted'])
x = np.array(days).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(line1)
x_ = PolynomialFeatures(degree=7, include_bias=True).fit_transform(x)
print(x_)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_, y)
r_sq = model.score(x_, y)
print(f"coefficient of determination: {r_sq}")
y_pred = model.predict(x_)
for i in range(len(line1)):
  pass
plt.plot(days, y_pred, label = 'Prediction')
print(f"tommorow's prediction is: {model.predict(days[-1] + 1)}")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```